# Creating a specific kind of Index in Power Pivot (DAX)

Tags: indexing, dax, powerpivot

I have a problem creating a specific kind of index column. The idea is that everytime a value occurs in a row, in column B, a new index begins. But when the value stops appearing, the index should stop and reset, when a new value appears.

I have a picture below that shows how it looks before added the index and after.

[image]

As you see, the Index is resetteting everytime a new "Yes" appears in column B. What I have tried so far is the RANKX('Table',Table[Something],"YES",ASC), but I am not sure whether I get closer to a correct  method or there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you show two tables BEFORE and AFTER the new value appears? And possibly the desired results.

Comment: Hi there. Sure I will Edit it where a before and an after appears

Comment: And where is the new Yes in "after reality"? Show also an additional index column with desired results that you would welcome, because I imagine that you are unhappy with the column "new column index".

Comment: Why do you have 1 value in 4 days. If that 1 is desired results how did you calculate it?